# Mapping differences between hibernate and jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i am new to JPA , while reading a tutorial on JPA

I couldn't able to find the difference in relationship mapping in hibernate and JPA

Are they same ??
Or Is there any difference in mapping with another table like one One-to-Many or One-to-One ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is a JPA implementation. It follows the JPA specifications, and has additional proprietary mapping capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But i am  not able to get "has additional proprietary mapping capabilities" in ur answer. Is relationship mapping same in hibernate and jpa ?? Plz guide me...

Comment: It's the same, but Hibernate allows mapping aditional kinds of associations, like ManyToAny for example.

Comment: Do u say hibernate is flexible for mapping rather than JPA ??

Comment: I don' know how to say it in another way: JPA defines various mapping possibilities which, in 99.0 % of the cases, are sufficient. Hibernate adds other mapping possibilities, for rare legacy situations. WHat about reading the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I didn't walk through documentation since i was going through simple tutorials,i will look into it.One more thing is i have seen ur profile many times, i was not expected ur reply :) Nice talking to you :)